# How to create a secondary buttons list on Order Admin Grid Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, filter, uicomponent

I need to add some group filters to Order Admin grid, so I want to create a secondary buttons list on it.

[image]

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

you can follow this in node listingToolbar or buttons

> vendor\magento\module-sales\view\adminhtml\ui_component\sales_order_grid.xml

add block listingToolbar name top2, and the result layout, you can follow this to add a button.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can follow this in node listingToolbar or buttons

> vendor\magento\module-sales\view\adminhtml\ui_component\sales_order_grid.xml

Comment: You can give an example?